Fetching the abstract/comment for a person's label
I'm trying to build a python function which given a surface form (label) of a person's name (eg. 'Shah Abbas I') will retrieve the abstract and the comment associated with it.
As the label could have variations, I am trying to first find all objects that have that surface as a label, using a Virtuoso BIF verb. Here is the python string I am building interpolating "surface":
query = f"""
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX bif: <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/bif#>

SELECT ?subject ?label
WHERE {{
    ?subject rdfs:label ?label .
    ?label bif:contains "'{surface}'" .
}}
"""

this query would return something like this in results["results"]["bindings"] :
[0] -> {'subject': {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Shah_Abbas_I'}, 'label': {'type': 'literal', 'xml:lang': 'en', 'value': 'Shah Abbas I'}}
[1] -> {'subject': {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mausoleum_of_Shah_Abbas_I'}, 'label': {'type': 'literal', 'xml:lang': 'en', 'value': 'Mausoleum of Shah Abbas I'}}
[2] -> {'subject': {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Shah_Abbas_I_the_Great'}, 'label': {'type': 'literal', 'xml:lang': 'en', 'value': 'Shah Abbas I the Great'}}
[3] -> {'subject': {'type': 'uri', 'value': "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Shah_Abbas_I's_invasions_of_Georgia"}, 'label': {'type': 'literal', 'xml:lang': 'en', 'value': "Shah Abbas I's invasions of Georgia"}} 

and then I would attempt to look into each of these to see if they have a http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects subject and if so return the object URI and in that try and find a comment/abstract.
For example amongst the triples found with:
SELECT ?property ?value
WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Shah_Abbas_I> ?property ?value .
}

I can see:
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abbas_the_Great

and so finally from this last page I could get and obtain abstract/comment.
I am quite lost :( Is the logic wrong? Is there a simpler way? Any Virtuoso dependent speedup very much appreciated.

there is no simpler way in standard SPARQL as the redirect thing is something DBpedia specific which you have to consider.

I'd start with something like SELECT ?subject ?label ?abstract WHERE {     ?subject rdfs:label ?label .     ?label bif:contains "'Shah_Abbas'" .     ?subject dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/dbo:abstract ?abstract    FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract), "en")) }

The query suggested by @UninformedUser appears likely to deliver what you want, with reasonable speed. Full query (with some extra optional whitespace) presented here, because it's much clearer than in the comment —
SELECT ?subject ?label ?abstract 
WHERE
  { ?subject  rdfs:label                           ?label . 
    ?label    bif:contains                         "'Shah_Abbas'" . 
    ?subject  dbo:wikiPageRedirects?/dbo:abstract  ?abstract 
                FILTER ( LANGMATCHES ( LANG ( ?abstract ), "en" ) )
  }

Also see the query in the DBpedia SPARQL input form, and the results thereof.

TYVM this is very useful even though for some of my things I am abandoning structure and relying on text from Wikipedia :(
